# Android in Turkmen

Tags: settings, languages

Is it possible to use Android in the Turkmen language?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not by default come with Turkmen support (the closest is Turkish).  It would be possible for a ROM developer to add such support along with a keyboard that supported it (such as [MultiLing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin)).

[Language Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam) claims to be able to enable Turkmen on rooted Samsung devices running the stock Touchwiz firmware.